# find duplicate rows which differ only by one categorical value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',\
                          'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],'C' :[1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6],'D',[11,11,12,12,13,14,15,16]})
```

I would like to filter this dataframe to keep only the rows where A is equale to 'foo' and that have no duplicate rows with the only difference that A is 'bar':

In this case:

```
df2=    A  C  D
   4  foo  3  13 
   6  foo  5  15
   7  foo  6  16
```

It would be better if it could generalize with additional categorical values for 'A', giving the option to choose which tuples of these 'A' values are to be removed example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz',\
                          'foo', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo'],'C' :[1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

when the tuple to be removed is ('foor','bar') should result in rows 2,4,6,7 to be kept

Comment: `df2 = df[df['A'] == 'foo']`.

Comment: Yes but I would like to remove the following rows 'foo' 1, 'foo' 2 because 'bar' 1 and 'bar' 2 are in the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for check values converted to `set`s and then [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby('C')['A'].transform(lambda x: set(x) == set(['foo']))]
print (df)
     A  C
4  foo  3
6  foo  5
7  foo  6
```

EDIT:

```
df = df[df.groupby(['C', 'D'])['A'].transform(lambda x: set(x) == set(['foo']))]
print (df)
     A  C   D
4  foo  3  13
6  foo  5  15
7  foo  6  16
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby(['C', 'D'])['A'].transform(lambda x: set(x) == set(['foo'])))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
7     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 10000

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice(['foo','bar','baz'], N),
                   'C': np.random.randint(1000,size=N),
                   'D': np.random.randint(1000,size=N)})
#print (df)

In [149]: %timeit (df[df.groupby(['C', 'D'])['A'].transform(lambda x: set(x) == set(['foo']))])
1 loop, best of 3: 2.54 s per loop

In [150]: %timeit (df.groupby(['C', 'D']).filter(lambda x: (x['A'] == 'foo').all()))
1 loop, best of 3: 6.21 s per loop
```

Comment: would that work also if there are more columns to be checked for equality?

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Also I add timings, because I think `transform` should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter`

```
In [5331]: df.groupby(['C', 'D']).filter(lambda x: (x['A'] == 'foo').all())
Out[5331]:
     A  C   D
4  foo  3  13
6  foo  5  15
7  foo  6  16
```

Comment: if you have more than just foo and bar, say baz. Can this still work?

Comment: Doesn't it? it checks for all foo, doesn't care about baz or jaz, try it

Comment: Yes it would be better if it could generalize with additional categorical values for 'A', giving the option to choose which tuples of these 'A' values are to be removed

Comment: @Sabor -- Updated the solution